# how I can to select several objects in Evolus Pencil?

Tags: mockups, mockup-tool, evolus-pencil

there is a form in a EvolusPencil-document with a lot of controls (objects) on it
how can I select several controls on this form without clicking each of them holding CTRL-key?

Answer (score 2):

You need to lock any of the objects around the objects you want to select by right clicking on the objects and selecting "Locked" from the context menu.

Here is a video detailing this:
http://screencast.com/t/A5ll3PZOu